# Update Column in Multiple Row With Random Code

Tags: postgresql

Hello I am trying to generate a unique code for each user in my database.
The code is a combination of the first letter of their first name, first letter of their last name, a '-', a random string of 6 char length, and the last two digits of the current year.

This is my code:

```
UPDATE user_info SET code = (SELECT UPPER(substring(first_name FROM 1 FOR 1))
             || UPPER(substring(last_name FROM 1 FOR 1))
       || '-'
         || (SELECT UPPER(array_to_string(array((
   SELECT SUBSTRING('abcdefghjklmnpqrstuvwxyz23456789'
                    FROM mod(FLOOR(random()*32)::int, 32)+1 FOR 1)
   FROM generate_series(1,6))),'')))
             || '-'
       || to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'YY'))
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM user_info);
```

This works however the middle part which is supposed to be a random string gets repeated for every column.

Comment: If your goal is to create a unique code for each user, I would suggest using a Sequence instead. It's better to know for sure that every user will have a unique identifier rather than relying on a random number, the date, and their name. I know the odds are *incredibly* low that, with your current method, there will be code duplicates, but why not change 99.9% to 100% with a Sequence? Or, better yet, add on a more detailed date (20171215082612, for example).

Comment: Thanks for your time, I am required to generate the code in exactly this format unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subselect is only evaluated once.

Try with a `VOLATILE` function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rand(integer) RETURNS text
   LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE STRICT AS
$$SELECT string_agg(
            substring('ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789'
                      FROM (random() * 32 + 0.5)::integer
                      FOR 1),
            ''
         )
FROM generate_series(1, $1)$$;
```

Then use

```
UPDATE user_info
SET code = upper(substring(first_name FROM 1 FOR 1)) ||
           upper(substring(last_name FROM 1 FOR 1)) ||
           '-' || rand(6) || '-' ||
           to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'YY')
WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL;
```

The weird `WHERE` condition is an optimization of your weird `WHERE` condition (maybe you don't need it at all).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Using functions would allow this, so:

```
create or replace function randomids(first text, last text) returns text as $$
   begin
   return (select upper(substring(first from 1 for 1))
   || upper(substring(last from 1 for 1))
   || '-'
   || (select upper(array_to_string(array((
       select substring('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz23456789'
       from mod(floor(random()*32)::int, 32)+1 for 1)
       from generate_series(1,6))),'')))
   || '-'
   || to_char(current_date, 'YY'));
   end;
   $$ language plpgsql;
```

And then you can update using the function:

```
update user_info uo set code = (
   select randomids(ui.first_name, ui.last_name)
   from user_info as ui
   where ui.user_id = uo.user_id)
   where uo.user_id in (select user_id from user_info);
```